# How can I test login rest API service using postman?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Here is my code Rest service code:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{


    private TradeFinancesDBEntities db = new TradeFinancesDBEntities();

    // POST: api/Demo
            [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Users/Login")]
    public IHttpActionResult Login(Credential user)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var log = db.tf_company_users.Where(x => x.Username == user.UserName && x.tf_password.Password_name == user.PassWord && x.tf_password.IsActive == "Y" && x.tf_company.Company_name == user.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (log != null)
        {

            return Ok(true);
        }
        return Ok(log);
    }
```

Ad Here is my Model class:

```
{
    public class Credential
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PassWord { get; set; }

    }
}
```

this is my Routeconfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

this is my WebApiConfig:
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml"));
    }

}
```

Now when I am trying to test in PostMan, I am getting 404 not found. Am I missing something ??

[postmman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aca6B.png)

Comment: 404 means "page not found".

Comment: Your action doesn't seem to accept Post. Have you got `[HttpPost]` attribute on your action?

Comment: Probably you did not post to the correct URL, or used the wrong HTTP method. Please post a shortened version of your `User` controller, showing all used attributes and the `Login` function.

Comment: Yes.. I know that.. But I am asking why I am getting this?? what I am missing

Comment: @weichch I tried with HttpPost attribute also.. No luck

Comment: What is your route? `/api/User/Login`? Can you make call to other methods?

Comment: You will get a 404 response if you are posting to the wrong URL.  The URL depends on the *route* that is configured for the method.  If there is no specific route, then the default route is used, which usually depends on the name of controller the method is in.  So tell us, what is the name of the controller class that contains this method?  What type of controller is it -- `Controller` or `ApiController`?   And most importantly, can you show us what routes you have set up in your `RouteConfig`?  (Look for `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start`.)

Comment: @BrianRogers I have update the code here.. Please let me know where I am doing mistakes

Comment: Your PostMan screenshot shows that you are posting to `/User/Login`, but the route configured for your Login method appears to be `/api/User/Login`.

Comment: @BrianRogers thanks..Yes I was posting wrong url in postman.. but the new problem is value is coming null.. Can you tell me what actually I am missing ?

Comment: What value is null?